# Unable to add external libraries in my tomcat application

Tags: java, tomcat

i'm using Tomcat7 and JRE7 with windows.

I tried to do different application using different libraries , but i always get classnotfoundexception for external libraries. I always put them into WEB-INF/lib, so tomcat should see them, but it doesn't.

I don't know if it is important but when i try to install tomcat i get the following error:

The system cannot find the Register Key for service 'tomcat7'

Some ideas?

Comment: See if standalone .zip download works, instead of windows service installer. Should be able to download, unzip and run tomcat-dir/bin/startup.bat without having to setup a service.